# Google Drive Api service accounts without Google Apps

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to build connector for my google drive account via google api oauth service account. I am using official gooogle client libraries for java.

```
public static Drive getDriveService() throws GeneralSecurityException,
            IOException, URISyntaxException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
                .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(new String[]{DriveScopes.DRIVE}))
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
                .setServiceAccountUser(ACCOUNT_USER)
                .build();
        Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credentials)
                .setHttpRequestInitializer(credentials).build();
        return service;
    }
```

It's pretty much basic sample from docs. Problem is it does not work. After execution I got `NullPointerException` on json deserialization.

So I debug this code with source code to google libraries and I found that httpRequest for access token returns status code 401 and content is null. I used same approach for Google Calendar API and it works without any problems.

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Or is there another way to access my files without user interaction? thanks